# On multiple devices, remove notifications if they have been read on one device

Tags: notifications

I use two cell phones and multiple devices. I work in the US and live in Canada. When I cross the border and turn on my Nexus 4, I get every notification sent since it was turned off. If it was one week or two, I still get them.

I want to keep notifications on when I use the phone. How do I eliminate all of the notifications (FB, Email) I've already gotten on another device?

Comment: That seems to be a lot of work. Do you have a lead?

Comment: I have wished for almost exactly the same thing, and I think mine would also be an acceptable solution to OP, so... is there a way for notifications that have been **acknowledged** (tapped on, or swiped away) on one device to be cleared from another device? i.e. synchronize the notifications (I often leave some notifications in the shade so I remember to act on them when I get home, for example - I would still want those to display on my other device)

Comment: If you connect an android wear smartwatch to the two smartphones wouldn't it be updated when a notifications is swiped away on one smartphone and then updated the other one?